# The sum of the reciprocal of squarefree numbers

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

Let $p_1, p_2, p_3... p_n$ be any number of odd prime numbers.

and let $s_1, s_2, s_3... s_k$ be all the squarefree numbers which have $p_1, p_2, p_3... p_n$

as prime factors.

Now I speculate that we always have that the sum of reciprocal of these numbers is never

an integer, no matter which odd primes we choose.

That is

$$\sum\limits_{w = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{p_w}}}}  + \sum\limits_{w = 1}^k {\frac{1}{{{s_w}}}}  = \frac{c}{d}$$

where c does not divide d.

There are one example where $$\sum\limits_{w = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{p_w}}}}  + \sum\limits_{w = 1}^k {\frac{1}{{{s_w}}}}  = 1
$$

but this uses the prime number 2.

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} = 1
$$

Is it true that there are no odd prime solutions to this or that the number of solutions is finite ?